# what does this line interpret

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

This is a python piece of code, I am trying to find out how the value is calculated and stored in the variable string_width.

```
string_width =len(" ".join(map(str,range(num,0,-1)))+" ".join(map(str,range(2,num+1))))
```

Any explanations will help.

Comment: Spaghetti code that screams "please rewrite me!"

Comment: Try printing out the parts you don't understand, e.g. `print(" ".join(map(str,range(num,0,-1))))`. Also which python is this? It can't be both 2 and 3.

Comment: if you break the statement down into its two joins `" ".join(..)` and print each of those joins, you might notice the pattern. The first join counts-*down* from `num` to zero (0), and the second join counts-*up* from 2 to `num`, then `len` length function gets called on it.

Comment: @AGNGazer this might not work for num = 0 & num = 1

Comment: @AGNGazer It will fail for n >= 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What actually gets output is very dependent on what `num` equals, but to understand this specific line of code you must break down the individual functions.

First, internally there are two iterable maps created with strings using the map function.

The first is all the numbers from the variable `num` counting down to 0, non inclusive. So if `num` was 4, this map would have 4, 3, 2, and 1 in it.

The second map starts at 2 and counts up to `num + 1`, non inclusive. So if `num` was 4, it would be 2, 3, and 4 in the map.

Next, both of the maps are joined with spaces so each one becomes a string with spaces in between each of its values. The first map from the previous example would be `"4 3 2 1"` and the second would be `"2 3 4"`. The + then concatenates these two strings together so they become a single string, which would be from our examples `"4 3 2 12 3 4"`.

Finally, len finds the length of this combined string and that value is saved into `string_width`, which in our example would be 12, because that is how many characters there are (it counts spaces).